# 20.04 boots from SSD but not if HDDs are online

Tags: boot, server, 20.04

I have a Dell PowerEdge R510 with 8x4TB WD SATA HDDs, a 1TB Kingston SATA SSD plugged into the the PCIe x4 port, and a 1TB WD_Black AN1500 NVMe SSD plugged into the PCIe x8 port.

I currently have Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed on the Kingston drive.

The OS will boot perfectly fine and I'm able to see the SSD and NVMe in cockpit, as long as I eject all 8 of the HDDs before I turn the system on.

As soon as I plug the 8x4TB HDDs back in and reboot, the system won't recognize the OS.

It may also be important to note that each of the HDDs are online and configured as Virtual Drives through the utility configuration screen at startup.

Everything seems to be fine and dandy but I can't figure out if I configured something incorrectly or if I need to update/remove the RAID card which is PERC H700.

Any advice or help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the `BOOT` flag set on one or more of the partitions on the 8x4TB drives.

Unmount (`umount`) them, and use `gparted` to clear the `BOOT` flag(s) on the 4TB drives.

Your BIOS steps through the disk controllers, steps through each disk connected to the controller to find the fIrst partition with the `BOOT` flag set, and boots from that partition.   If there is a system there, all is good. If there isn't, all is not good.

Comment: Thank you @waltinator that's what needed to happen.